# Filter an array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift

I have some data that mocks an api call like this:

```
 var people:Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> = [
     ["name":"harry", "age": 28, "employed": true, "married": true],
     ["name":"larry", "age": 19, "employed": true, "married": true],
     ["name":"rachel", "age": 23, "employed": false, "married": false]
 ]
```

I want to iterate over this data and return a result that contains only married people above twenty. How do I do this? I tried starting like this:

```
var adults:Array = []

for person in people {
    for(key:String, value:AnyObject) in person {
        println(person["age"])
    }
}
```

But then got stuck on how to proceed. Also I wanted to use a `map` closure. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let adults = people.filter { person in
    return person["married"] as Bool && person["age"] as Int > 20
}
```

Comment: error I get is: `Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments`

Comment: You need to change `AnyObject` to `Any` in your declaration of `people`.

Comment: Yep, this was the first thing I tried as well Rob, but it fails to compile "Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:10:38: error: could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments
    return person["married"] as Bool && person["age"] as Int > 20
"

Answer (score 3):

```
var people: Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = [
    ["name":"harry", "age": 28, "employed": true, "married": true],
    ["name":"larry", "age": 19, "employed": true, "married": true],
    ["name":"rachel", "age": 23, "employed": false, "married": false]
]

let oldMarriedPeople = filter(people) { (person: Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Bool in
        let age = person["age"] as Int
        let married = person["married"] as Bool
        return age > 20 && married
}

for p in oldMarriedPeople {
    println(p)
}
```

Comment: I error I get is `Could not find an overload for 'filter' that accepts the supplied arguments` - this is on the line that starts the filter

Comment: I only tested this on beta 1, something may have changed slightly in beta 2 that would force a minor change.

Comment: I tried this in a beta2 playground and it instantly crashes Xcode.  It does look valid to me though.

Comment: this crashes the beta2 playground for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let old = people.filter { person in
    return (person["married"] as NSNumber).boolValue && (person["age"] as NSNumber).intValue > 20
}
```

Since you use AnyObject, you have to use them as NSNumbers

Or, you can change your declaration to `Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>` and use:

```
let old = people.filter { person in
    return person["married"] as Bool && person["age"] as Int > 20
}
```

Comment: Also note, that since you're mocking an existing API, you're probably retrieving JSON results that are getting parsed into NSArrays, NSDictionaries, and NSNumbers, so casting through NSNumber will be your long-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 5, `Array`, like any type that conforms to Sequence protocol, has a method called [`filter(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter). `filter(_:)` has the following declaration:

```
func filter(_ isIncluded: (Self.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.Element]
```

> Returns an array containing, in order, the elements of the sequence that satisfy the given predicate.

---

The following Playground codes show how to use `filter(_:)` in order to filter your array with the desired predicate:

```
let people: [[String : Any]] = [
    ["name" : "harry", "age" : 28, "employed" : true, "married" : true],
    ["name" : "larry", "age" : 19, "employed" : true, "married" : true],
    ["name" : "rachel", "age" : 23, "employed" : false, "married" : false]
]

let filterClosure = { (personDictionary: [String : Any]) -> Bool in
    guard let marriedBool = personDictionary["married"] as? Bool, let validAgeBool = personDictionary["age"] as? Int  else { return false }
    return marriedBool == true && validAgeBool > 20
}

let filteredPeople = people.filter(filterClosure)

print(filteredPeople)
/*
 prints:
 [["name": "harry", "age": 28, "employed": true, "married": true]]
 */
```